# Clarify what happens to unanswered bounties

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty states:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

But it doesn't say what happens if no answer has at least 2 upvotes, e.g. if the bounty question is unanswered.

I propose this change:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer with at least 2 upvotes, the unawarded bounty is lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good idea; I added this clarifying text to that part of the /faq.